# Count and sort by the number of occurences in an array

Tags: elasticsearch, querydsl

I have a type named **account** with the following mapping:

```
        "country" : {
          "type" : "text",
          "fields" : {
            "keyword" : {
              "type" : "keyword",
              "ignore_above" : 256
            }
          }
        },
        "followingClientIds" : {
          "type" : "text",
          "fields" : {
            "keyword" : {
              "type" : "keyword",
              "ignore_above" : 256
            }
          },
          "fielddata" : true
        },
```

The `followingClientIds` is an array of string ids from other accounts that I follow.

I want to build a query that gets every account from a country and sort them by the count of mutual accounts that we both follow.

Here are some of the queries I did until now:

```
GET account/_search
{
  "size": 20,
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "filter": {
        "term": {
          "country.keyword": "AT"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "sort": [
    {
      "followingClientIds.keyword": {
        "order": "asc",
        "nested_filter": {
          "terms": {
            "followingClientIds.keyword": [
              "dFbEW23hVZ3w8jhH9LeCw3QG33UjuF5C"
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

For instance, I have this 3 docs in account type:

```
{
    "username": "user2",
    "country": "AT",
    "followingClientIds": ["abc"]
},
{
    "username": "user3",
    "country": "AT",
    "followingClientIds": ["abc", "bcd", "cde"]
},
{
    "username": "user4",
    "country": "AT",
    "followingClientIds": ["abc"]
}
```

Imagine I'll send to the query the **country** and the **followingClientIds** to sort:

```
{
    "country": "AT",
    "followingClientIds": ["abc", "bcd", "cde"]
}
```

I want the results to be like this:

```
{
    "username": "user3",
    "country": "AT",
    "followingClientIds": ["abc", "bcd", "cde"],
    "fields": [ // dont really need this custom field, but would be cool
        "mutual_following_count": 3
    ]
},
{
    "username": "user2",
    "country": "AT",
    "followingClientIds": ["abc"],
    "fields": [
        "mutual_following_count": 1
    ]
},
{
    "username": "user4",
    "country": "AT",
    "followingClientIds": ["abc"],
    "fields": [
        "mutual_following_count": 1
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're looking for a standalone, [computed field](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/kibana/current/scripted-fields.html) called `mutual_following_count`, you can do just that with the script below. But you [won't be able to sort on it](https://discuss.elastic.co/t/sorting-on-value-from-script-field/206377/2).

The only other alternative is scripted sorting which first calculates a value and then sorts by it. The resulting query could then look like this:

```
{
  "size": 20,
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "filter": {
        "term": {
          "country.keyword": "AT"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "sort": [
    {
      "_script": {
        "type": "number",
        "order": "desc", 
        "script": {
          "lang": "painless", 
          "params": {
            "followingClientIds": ["abc", "bcd", "cde"]
          },
          "source": """
            // deduplicate
            def fromSource = doc.followingClientIds
                                .stream()
                                .distinct()
                                .collect(Collectors.toList());
            def fromParams = params.followingClientIds
                                   .stream()
                                   .distinct()
                                   .collect(Collectors.toList());
            
            // size() is a float so cast
            return (int) fromParams.findAll(x -> fromSource.contains(x)).size();
          """
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

The downside is that you cannot 'name' that sort. Neither `mutual_following_count` nor anything else.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. The query does look like it's what I need but it is not sorting the results. I tried with `fromSource.stream().filter(x -> fromParams.contains(x)).count()` and it didn't work neither.

Comment: It seems like the `contains(x)` is not comparing right the values

Comment: Oh I see, the elements in the `List` are all **lowercase**, this is why `contains` was not working. Thanks!

Comment: Right, no prob! You may wanna look into `.keyword` to keep the capitalization.